# How to plot arcs between two cities on a globe map using ggplot and sf

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I have seen R codes generating a global map with ggplot and sf library, but I couldn't understand many of the details as I have limited knowledge in geography. Here is a visualization task I need to do with R.

If I have the coordinates (e.g. latitude and longitude) of two cities in the world, and I want to draw a red arc between them, which is the shorter arc on the great circle passing the two cities, how could I do that? The result should look like what we will get when we look up airline routes on google map.

Here is where I stopped at a fixed global map plot:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("sf")
world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
ggplot(data = world) +
    geom_sf() +
    coord_sf(crs = "some crs code")
```

The crs part requires specific knowledge in geography, I don't know what to use and the meaning of different codes.

Comment: Generally questions on SO are expected to include evidence of effort: first, at demonstrating coding of the data-setup and then at starting to put relevant packages into your workspace and show at what point you need assistance. Anything less is just asking SO to be a “code - server”. We don’t see ourselves that way.

Comment: I have done that days before, but couldn't find a solution that helps. What's the duplicate? Could you provide me with the link?

Comment: Noting that asking us to search for you is likewise considered off-topic, and that you have not fulfilled the other obligations set forth in the help pages: [help], [ask], [MCVE] iI choose rather than offering a duplicate, to offer the search strategy: "[r] plot great circle"

Comment: alright, your suggestion on the search also helps, thanks

Comment: I'm retracting my closevote. This Q attracted a wonderful answer. BUT, you _should_ have included sample data: specific cities at the very least with names and countries in a data object. Also you should have included references to map packages of which there are several to demonstrate that you had considered or attempted to use then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You may want to have a look to https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/ for getting an insight of what is spatial data.
- The `code` is the reference to the map projection. The world is a sphere(-ish) and the representation on a two-dimension surface (screen, paper, etc.) is a challenge. That's why there are so many different projections (see more on https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/spatial-class.html#crs-intro and https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/reproj-geo-data.html#crs-in-r). Check also https://epsg.io/ to find the codes of each projection.

Now, getting back to your question, you may want to plot "Great Circles" between cities, that is the curve that represent the shortest path between points on a sphere (flights uses these lines for optimizing the flight time and fuel):

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.1, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(rnaturalearth)
library(tidyverse)
world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")

# Get three cities
cities <- ne_download(type = "populated_places", returnclass = "sf") %>%
  filter(NAME %in% c("San Francisco", "Rio de Janeiro", "Oslo"))

# On Mercator
ggplot(world) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data=cities, color="red", size=3) +
  coord_sf(crs="EPSG:3857")
```

[image]

```r
# On Robinson projection
ggplot(world) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data=cities, color="red", size=3) +
  coord_sf(crs="ESRI:54030")
```

[image]

```r
# Create great circles
library(geosphere)

init <- cities %>% as("Spatial")
dest <- bind_rows(cities[-1,], cities[1,]) %>% as("Spatial")

lines <- gcIntermediate(
  init,
  dest,
  sp = TRUE,
  addStartEnd = TRUE,
  n = 100,
  breakAtDateLine = FALSE
)
#> Warning in showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO", prefer_proj
#> = prefer_proj): Discarded datum Unknown based on WGS84 ellipsoid in Proj4
#> definition

lines_sf <- st_union(st_as_sf(lines))

# Now we have the lines
ggplot(lines_sf) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data=cities, color="red")
```

[image]

```r
# Create a nice plot

ggplot(world) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data=lines_sf) +
  geom_sf(data=cities, color="red", size=3) +
  coord_sf(crs="+proj=laea +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +lon_0=-74 +lat_0=40")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I was conflicted about this answer. It's a really awesome answer and I hope it gets massively upvoted, but ... the question is so weak. (Will definitely investigate bestowing a bounty.)  I went to MetaSO where such occurrences are thrashed out and my thought is that I should now go do brain surgery on the question body to have a pairing of Q/A question quality. Maybe the questioner will come back an join the SO Community with improved understanding of what SO is hoping to be? He/she made a token effort but I thought it fell quite short of being an exemplar Q that deserved this exemplar A.